# How to match specific word in url.py in django?

Tags: django

I am new to dJango. I got the following url address `http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/%7B%25%20url%20'main'%20%25` but my app didn't find the address when looked up my `urls.py` as below.

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('main', views.main, name='main'),
    path('pageA',views.pageA,name='pageA')
]
```

I know that it can be resolved by applying the regular expression but I failed to get the right solution.

Comment: Where is your URL coming from? How is it being generated?

Comment: You can see the phrase `{% url 'main' %}` in your generated URL. In other words, this is a problem where you're rendering the template that contains the link, not in the URLs themselves.

Answer (score 0):

In you template use `{% url 'main' %}` and it will generate the url for you relating to `path('main', views.main, name='main'),`

Answer (score -1):

In Django we will be using the jinja template to reduce the effort of mapping the urls .

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   path('main', views.main, name='main'),
   path('pageA',views.pageA,name='pageA')
]
```

In url.py , while defining the url path , we will be introducing an attribute

`name = "<how do you call the url; like alias>"`.

In order to map it from the templates , 
Use "{% url 'main' %}" => here you are indirectly calling the url path with main as the name attribute . When you do so you wont be facing with this issue.

Thanks